# Can't new users edit their own questions without approval?

Tags: discussion, editing

Found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/392958/bash-alias-history-substitution-similar-to-in-csh) with a suggested edit pending edit. But it looks like it's the OP that has done the edit. Shouldn't this be approved automatically?

[image]

Comment: Seriously, nobody here could be bothered to approve the user's own edit?

Comment: @DanielBeck - I left it so that other 10k users could view it.

Comment: @Nifle You don't even need to be registered to access [this](http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/9024).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Users never need to suggest edits to their own posts, they can either edit outright (the norm) or they can't because edits are blocked (eg, post is locked).

In this case, the edit was proposed at ~16:49 and on the user account history I can see that a user account merge happened at ~17:11.

It is highly likely that the user returned to the site on a different account (they are unregistered, so they simply used a different computer/browser or don't keep their cookies) and so *wasn't* the question's owner when they suggested the edit, but that account has since been merged in to the original.

Comment: nice catch, @DMA!

Comment: Oh right, forgot to approve their edit after the merge. Now, if only there was a feature request to handle such a small edge case of auto-approving, but not repping, merged users with pending suggested edits on their own posts.